# Porque comparar Enum com um Objeto enum

Tags: java, enums

Quando estava aprendendo Java, eu tinha uma Class que tinha uma propriedade do tipo **Enum**,
e, em um certo momento, eu queria saber se o que estava vindo em um Método era igual a uma constante da **Enum**, algo assim:

```
public void teste( TipoAlteracaoValor valor ) {
        if( valor.equals(TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR) ) {
            System.out.println( "é Alteração ");
        }
        //Deveria ser assim:
        if( TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR.equals(valor)) {
            System.out.println("é Alteração" );
        }
    }
```

Mas me disseram que isso é errado de se fazer, o certo é comparar a Constante do **Enum** com o valor que estiver vindo pelo parâmetro. Porém não me lembro... qual é a razão técnica de ser usar essa comparação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema com `valor.equals(TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR)` é que se o parâmetro `valor` for nulo, então você receberá uma exceção `NullPointerException` por tentar acessar o método `equals` num objeto nulo.

A outra forma resolve o problema porque a "constante" `TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR` nunca será nula e, caso o parâmetro `valor` seja também não há problemas, simplesmente o `if` não vai ser executado.

Porém, posso dizer que a melhor forma de comparar Enums em Java não é nenhuma das duas apresentadas.

**Você pode simplesmente usar o operador `==`, como com tipos primitivos**.

O `==` quando aplicado a objetos verifica se os mesmos são a mesma instância. E isso é justamente a vantagem do Enum. Cada "constante" do Enum é na verdade uma instância única do mesmo.

Considere o código:

```java
public void teste( TipoAlteracaoValor valor ) {
    if( valor == TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR ) {
        System.out.println( "é Alteração ");
    }
}
```

Além de mais legível ele não incorre no problema com `null`.

---

Fontes sobre o assunto (em Inglês):

- [Comparing Java enum members: == or equals() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals)
- [Use == (or !=) to Compare Java Enums](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074292/core-java/use-----or-----to-compare-java-enums.html)

Answer (score 3):

Ao comparar como abaixo, você poderá tomar um NullPointerException. Imagine o que aconteceria se a variável valor estivesse nula:

```
    if( valor.equals(TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR) ) {
        System.out.println( "é Alteração ");
    }
```

Ao comparar o enum com o objeto que chegou, você evita tomar erro caso o atributo esteja NULL:

```
    if( TipoAlteracaoValor.ALTERACAO_VALOR.equals(valor)) {
        System.out.println("é Alteração" );
    }
```

Tanto faz se valor está null ou não, você não terá exceção.

Só isso mesmo. [=

Comment: Nada que uma checagem adicional `valor != null` não resolva (com a desvantagem de você ter que fazer essa checagem adicional :)

Comment: Uhum. Eu ainda assim prefiro o sem a checagem, é um if a menos. :3